# ng Route : can´t find html page

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

I have a MVC Visual Studio project and want to use the ngRoute.

I am using the IIS.

I am on the page http://localhost/555/Reservation/RoadMap and want to switch to 
http://localhost/555/Reservation/Map/SearchConnection

But I get the error. That it can´t find the ressoure: HTTP-Fehler 404.0 - Not Found.
I think I have a mistake in the templateURL.

my app:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/SearchConnection', {
        templateUrl: 'SearchConnection.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
 });
```

my Map.cshtml:

```
.....
<a href="SearchConnection">Search</a>
```

The folder structure is following:

root: MyWebApplication
-Views
--Reservation: Map.cshtml , SearchConnection.html

Comment: Are you sure the template URL is correct? If you are using MVC then you probably do not want to reference physical file location. Eg. templateUrl: '/Reservation/Map/SearchConnection'

Comment: need to use `#/` to prefix your angular paths if you aren't using html5Mode

Comment: <a ng-href="#/SearchConnection">Search</a> is not working. (but also no error) @Neil : What would be the best solution? As you can seee the Map.cshtml is a view from mvc and searchConnection.html is just a simple html.

Comment: What I have done in a solution is to have all my templateURLs as partial views. So if you were to browse to it you could go to http://localhost/555/Reservation/Map/SearchConnection. Then your route provider would be: when('/SearchConnection', {
        templateUrl: 'Reservation/Map/SearchConnection'
    })